# Python run package by calling the name in terminal

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setuptools, pypi, distutils

I'm learning writing python packages and I want it so that people can use it just by typing the package name in their terminal.

I've done something like this https://github.com/Tylerastro/MorseCode

So my way is setting the  `entry_points` in setup.py. So people can type `morse` in their terminal and directly call the main function. i.e., `morse` becomes an universal command in the computer.

1. My question is that is it the right way to achieve my goal? Or is
   there any way to do so without using `entry_points`? Thanks in
   advance.
2. Another question is: can I write a CLI with options to select and
   set values? Like using PLUTO, a simulation program in astronomy:

[image]

Comment: 1. "*…is it [`entry_points`] the right way to achieve my goal?*" Yes. "*…is there any way to do so without using entry_points?*" [`scripts`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts). 2. "*…can I write a CLI with options…?*" Yes but a) please don't ask 2 different questions at once; ask 2 separate questions; b) [The Rule Number One](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question: [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+parse+options), and research, and show your effort in the question.

Comment: Understood. I'll be aware of these in the future. Thank you for the answer and comments.